# pg_dump does not finish

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I am trying to backup our postgres database (8.4.17), which is about 25GB in size.

```
pg_dump database_name > database_db_dump_2014-05-05.sql
```

unfortunately, the backup stops after about 600MB in, and does not continue. It always stops when trying to dump a specific table (fb_crawler_event). I was able to successfully dump all the other tables using the `--table` swtich. I have already stopped any other process that could interact with the database.

---

server log after a restart of the DB (looks ok to me):

```
2014-05-05 14:34:46 CEST LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2014-05-05 14:34:46 CEST LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-05-05 14:32:50 CEST
2014-05-05 14:34:46 CEST LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2014-05-05 14:34:46 CEST LOG:  record with zero length at 1A1/AD6A78C0
2014-05-05 14:34:46 CEST LOG:  redo is not required
2014-05-05 14:34:47 CEST LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2014-05-05 14:34:47 CEST LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

---

verbose output from pg_dump (nothing suspicious, but the obvious table, which doesn't let the database continue to dump)

`... lots of lines ...
pg_dump: restoring data for table "django_site"
pg_dump: dumping contents of table django_site
pg_dump: restoring data for table "fb_crawler_event"
pg_dump: dumping contents of table fb_crawler_event`

And then it just halts.

---

output from the pg_locks table, which seems to be huge to me (294 entries all together):

```
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction |  pid  |      mode       | granted 
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-------+-----------------+---------
 relation   |    16384 |     2674 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 1/23               | 19526 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   |    16384 |    27367 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 1/23               | 19526 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   |    16384 |   695092 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 1/23               | 19526 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   |    16384 |     2675 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 2/7                | 18960 | AccessShareLock | t
 relation   |        0 |     2671 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 1/23               | 19526 | AccessShareLock | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 2/7        |               |         |       |          | 2/7                | 18960 | ExclusiveLock   | t
...
```

I am no expert in postgres, so I am wondering if the database is corrupt?

How can I further debug this anomaly?

Comment: Could you try `create table x as select * from fb_crawler_event` and `pg_dump` that?

Comment: I just tried, and the command is stuck just like `pg_dump` itself, so it seems I cannot select on some rows or something...

Comment: That narrows it down a bit! Do you have an estimate of the number of rows in that table? I wonder if bisecting the table (using `limit n` and `offset n+1`) will work or if these commands will also get stuck?

Comment: And, if you haven't already, read the PostgreSQL page on corruption: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Are there any rows in pg_locks where granted is not true?

Comment: @jjanes No, all the locks are granted.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Thanks, I will try to pin down the row(s) that cause issue in that way! And I'll read everything about possible corruption issues.

Comment: I've in the kernel log, and it seems I had a `Oops` somewhen... Also, I am not able to copy the raw database (without pg_dump) anywhere, so I'm suspecting a hardware failure. Damn.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to figure out which file in the database storage was the culprit, by copying all the files to /dev/null.

```
cp -vR /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4 /dev/null
```

(The path to your DB files might differ)

The currupt file could not be copied, but there was nothing I could do to change that. (so it was most probably a FS error or hardware failure)

So I restarted the server with a forced fsck (e.g. `touch /forcefsck`), to make sure the FS would do the best to fix itself. This might not be the way you'll want to go, since it is possible to have a total data loss afterwards, but I was able to preserve the most precious data already beforehand, so I took the risk.

After reboot I could finally access the inaccessable table again, but I am not sure, if the data contained is corrupted or not. Anyway, I do have a backup now, which I can disect to find out, and my server can go back online for now...

I recommend reading the [wiki of postgres about corruption](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption) and the [slides of this FOSDEM presentation](http://thebuild.com/presentations/worst-day-fosdem-2014.pdf) for some more info on DB corruption